# How to use fluentbit with Nestjs?

Tags: node.js, logging, nestjs, fluentd, fluent-bit

I have a fluentbit running in the Docker container 192.168.1.201:24224 which is connected to the elasticsearch.
Now, I am trying to connect my nestjs logger to the fluentbit:
logger.ts

```
import * as winston from 'winston';
var config = {
  host: '192.168.1.201',
  port: 24224,
  timeout: 3.0,
  requireAckResponse: true, // Add this option to wait response from Fluentd certainly
};
var fluentTransport = require('fluent-logger').support.winstonTransport();
var fluent = new fluentTransport('test', config);
// Initialize Winston Logger

const logger = winston.createLogger({
  level: 'verbose',
  format: winston.format.json(),
  defaultMeta: { service: 'test-service' },
  transports: [
    fluent,
    new winston.transports.Console({
      format: winston.format.json(),
    }),
  ],
});
export default logger;
```

I am using the logger in this way:
loggservice.ts:

```
async log_info(
    tracking_id: any,
  ) {
    logger.log({
      tracking_id: tracking_id,
    });
  }
```

then, in the function :
test.ts:

```
log_info(tracking_id)
```

It seems that it can not send the log to the fluentbit(so that I can get the log in ES), am I missing something here?

Comment: Please add the errors that you're getting to your question. Is network connectivity fine between these containers i.e. `192.168.1.201` is reachable from then container that your app is running?

Comment: Hi, there are no errors. I just can not get the log in ES. the networking is good.